# Reading 64 bit value from coprocessor on arm

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to read the pmcntr variable from an arm chip (Cortex-A72) chip.   I can read the 32 bit version as follows:

```
asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r" (pmccntr));
```

But I'm not sure how to read it as a 64 bit.   In the [arm documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100095_0003_06_en/way1382543399848.html), it has the following table:

```
0x0F8   c9   0   c13 0  PMCCNTR[31:0]   RW  32-bit  Performance Monitors Cycle Count Register a
0x0FC   -    -   -   -  PMCCNTR[63:32]
-       -    0   c9  -  PMCCNTR[63:0]       64-bit
```

But I'm not sure how to read a 64 bit value.   I'm taking it it has to do with `mrc2` or `mrrc`, but I can't find any good documentation on how these are used or how they differ from `mrc` ...

Comment: Yes, use `mrrc` as per the table, e.g. `mrrc coproc, #0, Rt, Rt2, c9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm taking it it has to do with ... `mrrc`, but I can't find any good documentation on how these are used or how they differ from `mrc`

According to the [ARMv8 reference manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/db/DDI0487D_b_armv8_arm.pdf), pages 4102 and 4103, `mrc` is used to access a 32-bit system (in older ARM architectures: co-processor) register; according to pages 4104 and 4105, `mrrc` is used to access a 64-bit system register.

The syntax is: `MRRC <coproc>, #<opc1>, <Rt>, <Rt2>, <CRm>` while the CPU register `<Rt>` will receive the lower 32 bits and the CPU register `<Rt2>` will receive the higher 32 bits of the 64-bit system register.

> I'm taking it it has to do with `mrc2` ...

The ARMv8 manual casually mentions the `mrc2` instruction but it does not describe this instruction. However, the ARMv7 manual does:

The instruction `mrc2` seems to be intended for third-party extensions designed by semiconductor manufacturers who produce microcontrollers using an ARM core.

The `mrc2` instructions will only work on a microcontroller that has such extensions.